# NIS users can't use yppasswd on client machines

Tags: debian, nis

I'm administrating a system where users authenticate via NIS and things went wrong when a user tried to use `yppasswd` to change her password. She got the error:

```
yppasswd: yppasswdd not running on NIS master host ("localhost").
```

Based on suggestions elsewhere around the Web, I tried setting an entry in `/etc/hosts` with the client's IP (as opposed to `127.0.0.1`) pointing to the client's host name. This didn't work.

My `/etc/yp.conf` says `ypserver <my_server_IP>`.

`strace` output shows that `yppasswd` consults `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` before deciding on `127.0.0.1` for the server.

What am I missing?

Client is running Debian 7.0 (Wheezy) and server is running Debian 6.0.1 (Squeeze)

**Note**

I'm aware that NIS is nearing total obsolescence and very vulnerable. 
A migration to LDAP is on my agenda, but I need a solution for this in the interim.

**Additional Details**

Files on the client:

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
<IP in current DHCP lease> host_name.domain host_name
<server_ip> server_name server_name.domain
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:         files nis compat
group:          files nis compat
shadow:         files nis compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: What is currently in the clients `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` files?

Comment: @JoelTaylor Updated question...